# New items are populated into `Send to` menu without obvious pattern

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu, send-to

I found recently suddenly unexpected behavior of *Send to* right click context menu option.

Animation shows how in there suddenly arise items (and also disappear).

[image: GIF Animation]

Worth noting I used RShift+F10, LShift+F10 combinations to for context menu invocation. In Total Commander works also +F9 while LShift seems stable (and without failure) while RShift behaves similar to what can be seen in *File Explorer*.

Most of unwanted items **come from user folder**.

---

What could be reason for this? I am thinking about some file type (or other) handlers but I have no idea why they could work only *sometimes*. Maybe it relates to some time delays or it is just bug.

Answer (score 1):

> I found recently suddenly unexpected behavior of Send to right click
> context menu option.

This could be a shell context handler issue (hundreds of contexts to look through).  Use Nirsoft Shell View to look at contexts.  Needle in Haystack issue.

**(A) Try repair with DISM and SFC.**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**(B) If DISM does not resolve the issue, try Windows 10 Repair Install.**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Use the option to Keep Everything to begin with.

There are more aggressive options (Keep just Data and Keep Nothing) if the first option does not resolve the issue.